# center div in css but keep off of left nav

Tags: html, css, nav, centering

I am trying to center my ``` #content div`` on a page that also has a position:absolute #nav ``` on the left side. This `#nav` comes out to about `400px` from the left side of the page (accounting for the `<body> margin`).

Here's the code for the centering of both `divs`:

```
#nav{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 350px;
    height: 800px; 
}

#content{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 1000px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

This works fine enough, unless that is, the window becomes quite narrow, in which case the `#content` slides over the `#nav`. Is there a way to center the `#nav` on the page, relative to window size, but still put a limit on how far left it can move even while the window gets smaller?

EDIT: see jsfiddle demo of the situation here: [jsfiddle.net/b2bcofyd/1/#&togetherjs=gti1uzDgxF](http://jsfiddle.net/b2bcofyd/1/#&togetherjs=gti1uzDgxF) [i've modified the dimensions of the divs slightly to make it more legible in the demo]

Comment: Can you provide a full running sample ? or using plnkr

Comment: Yes see jsfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/b2bcofyd/1/#&togetherjs=gti1uzDgxF

[i've modified the dimensions of the divs slightly to make it more legible in jsFiddle]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a minimum width to the body. By adding this to your stylesheet:

```
body {
   min-width: 950px; /*350 + 600*/
}
```

This way, scrollbars appear when the window gets smaller than 950px;

As an alternative, you can wrap your content and nav in one div and center that div.

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="nav"> </div>
   <div id="content"> </div>
</div>
```

```
#wrapper {
   width: 950px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
#nav {
   float: left;
   width: 350px;
}
#content {
   float: left;
   width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: @Medda86, woops, that should have been `</#nav>` ofcourse ;)

Comment: Thanks.
The first solution seems elegant, and while the scroll bar does appear when the window gets below a certain size, the content div continues to slide left over the nav.

Comment: The second solution essentially does the same thing, except when the window get expanded again it seems to drag the left side nav bar towards the center..

Comment: Change the min width to 1000. Probably some margin, border or padding that causes that.